# nested content_tags escape inner html.. why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So, if I loop through and create a collection of li/a tags, I get as expected.. an array of these tags:

```
(1..5).to_a.map do
  content_tag(:li) do
    link_to("boo", "www.boohoo.com")
  end
end

=> ["<li><a href=\"www.boohoo.com\">boo</a></li>", "<li><a href=\"www.boohoo.com\">boo</a></li>", "<li><a href=\"www.boohoo.com\">boo</a></li>", "<li><a href=\"www.boohoo.com\">boo</a></li>", "<li><a href=\"www.boohoo.com\">boo</a></li>"]
```

I call join on them and I get an expected string...

```
(1..5).to_a.map do
  content_tag(:li) do
    link_to("boo", "www.boohoo.com")
  end
end.join

=> "<li><a href=\"www.boohoo.com\">boo</a></li><li><a href=\"www.boohoo.com\">boo</a></li><li><a href=\"www.boohoo.com\">boo</a></li><li><a href=\"www.boohoo.com\">boo</a></li><li><a href=\"www.boohoo.com\">boo</a></li>"
```

However, if I nest this one level deeper in an ol tag...

```
content_tag(:ol) do
  (1..5).to_a.map do
    content_tag(:li) { link_to("boo", "www.boohoo.com") } 
  end.join
end

 => "<ol>&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;www.boohoo.com&quot;&gt;boo&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;www.boohoo.com&quot;&gt;boo&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;www.boohoo.com&quot;&gt;boo&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;www.boohoo.com&quot;&gt;boo&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;www.boohoo.com&quot;&gt;boo&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;</ol>"
```

I get escaped inner-html madness!!!

When looking at the rails source code:

```
  def content_tag(name, content_or_options_with_block = nil, options = nil, escape = true, &block)
    if block_given?
      options = content_or_options_with_block if content_or_options_with_block.is_a?(Hash)
      content_tag_string(name, capture(&block), options, escape)
    else
      content_tag_string(name, content_or_options_with_block, options, escape)
    end
  end

  private

    def content_tag_string(name, content, options, escape = true)
      tag_options = tag_options(options, escape) if options
      "<#{name}#{tag_options}>#{escape ? ERB::Util.h(content) : content}</#{name}>".html_safe
    end
```

It deceivingly looks like I can just do:  content_tag(:li, nil, nil, false) and not have it escape the content..  However:

```
content_tag(:ol, nil, nil, false) do
  (1..5).to_a.map do
    content_tag(:li, nil, nil, false) do 
      link_to("boo", "www.boohoo.com")
    end
  end.join
end
=> "<ol>&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;www.boohoo.com&quot;&gt;boo&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;www.boohoo.com&quot;&gt;boo&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;www.boohoo.com&quot;&gt;boo&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;www.boohoo.com&quot;&gt;boo&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;www.boohoo.com&quot;&gt;boo&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;</ol>"
```

I still am suffering from unwanted html_escape syndrome...

So the only way I know to avoid this is to do:

```
content_tag(:ol) do
  (1..5).to_a.map do
    content_tag(:li) do 
      link_to("boo", "www.boohoo.com")
    end
  end.join.html_safe
end

=> "<ol><li><a href=\"www.boohoo.com\">boo</a></li><li><a href=\"www.boohoo.com\">boo</a></li><li><a href=\"www.boohoo.com\">boo</a></li><li><a href=\"www.boohoo.com\">boo</a></li><li><a href=\"www.boohoo.com\">boo</a></li></ol>"
```

But..  Why does this happen?

Comment: is this just represent purpose or some logic behaviour requires server-side to populate this block?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It happens because in Rails 3 the SafeBuffer class was introduced which wraps the String class and overrides the default escaping that would otherwise occur when concat is called.

In your case, the content_tag(:li) is outputting a proper SafeBuffer, but Array#join doesn't understand SafeBuffers and simply outputs a String. The content_tag(:ol) is then be called with a String as it's value instead of a SafeBuffer and escapes it. So it doesn't so much have to do with nesting as it does to do with join returning a String not a SafeBuffer.

Calling html_safe on a String, passing the String to raw, or passing the array to safe_join will all return a proper SafeBuffer and prevent the outer content_tag from escaping it.

Now in the case of passing false to the escape argument, this doesn't work when your passing a block to content tag because it is calling `capture(&block)` ActionView::Helpers::CaptureHelper which is used to pull in the template, or your case the output value of join, which then causes it to call `html_escape` on the string before it makes its way into the `content_tag_string` method.

```
  # action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb
  def content_tag(name, content_or_options_with_block = nil, options = nil, escape = true, &block)
    if block_given?
      options = content_or_options_with_block if content_or_options_with_block.is_a?(Hash)
      # capture(&block) escapes the string from join before being passed
      content_tag_string(name, capture(&block), options, escape)
    else
      content_tag_string(name, content_or_options_with_block, options, escape)
    end
  end

  # action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb
  def capture(*args)
    value = nil
    buffer = with_output_buffer { value = yield(*args) }
    if string = buffer.presence || value and string.is_a?(String)
      ERB::Util.html_escape string
    end
  end
```

Since value here is the return value from join, and join returns a String, it calls html_escape before the content_tag code even gets to it with it's own escaping.

Some reference links for those interested

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.1.0/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.1.0/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb

http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/

http://railsdispatch.com/posts/security

**Edit**

Another way to handle this is to do a map/reduce instead of map/join since if reduce is not passed an argument it will use the first element and run the given operation using that object, which in the case of map content_tag will be calling the operation on a SafeBuffer.

```
content_tag(:ol) do
  (1..5).to_a.map do
    content_tag(:li) do
      link_to(...)
    end
  end.reduce(:<<)
  # Will concat using the SafeBuffer instead of String with join
end
```

As a one-liner

```
content_tag(:ul) { collection.map {|item| content_tag(:li) { link_to(...) }}.reduce(:<<) }
```

Add a little meta-spice to clean things up

```
ul_tag { collection.map_reduce(:<<) {|item| li_link_to(...) } }
```

Who needs html_safe... this is Ruby!

Comment: Nice answer! How did you get to map_reduce? did you make your own method or is it built in Rails(Ruby)?

Comment: I just made that up, it's monkey patched on Enumerable, it's simply really, def map_reduce(op, &block) self.map(&block).reduce(op) end

Answer (score 5):

What happens if you use [`safe_join`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-safe_join)?

```
content_tag(:ol) do
  safe_join (1..5).to_a.map {
      content_tag(:li) { link_to("boo", "www.boohoo.com") } 
    }, ''
end
```

Or just use raw?

```
content_tag(ol) do
  1.upto(5) {
    raw content_tag(:li) { link_to 'boo', 'www.boohoo.com' }
    #  or maybe
    #    raw content_tag(:li) { raw link_to('boo', 'www.boohoo.com') } 
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not positive, but I think that the html escaping happens at each "layer" (for lack of a better term; each iteration)― what I mean is at the inner block level (1..5)…. and then at the outer block level (content_tag(:ol) do ...

Comment: I don't think so..  It happens from calling "join"..content_tag(:div) { content_tag(:ol) } outputs "<div><ol></ol></div>" ...  Where content_tag(:div) { [content_tag(:ol)].join } outputs "<div>&lt;ol&gt;&lt;/ol&gt;</div>"