# rails 4 escaping garbled html in nested content tags,

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a view helper method which I want to return a nested html string. The first and secondary layers are returning correctly formatted html (is this what is meant by 'escaped html'?). The third, however, is producing garbled text (is this 'unescaped'?).

```
"....content=\"test&lt;br/&gt;test&lt;br/&gt;test&lt;br/&gt;London&lt;br/&gt;test\"></meta></div></div>"
```

How do I ensure that nested content displays correctly, no matter how deep I go?

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562478/nested-content-tags-escape-inner-html-why) answer quite useful, although this is within context of looping, which here I am not doing.

Here's the method I am working with,

```
  def opening_times_meta(venue)
    content_tag(:div, nil, class: 'facility-type', itemscope: true, itemtype: 'http://schema.org/Event') do
      content_tag(:meta, nil, content: venue.title, itemprop: 'name' )
      content_tag(:div, nil, class: 'hidden', itemprop: 'location', itemscope: true, itemtype: 'http://schema.org/Place') do
        content_tag(:meta, nil, itemprop: 'sameAs', content: request.original_url).html_safe
        content_tag(:meta, nil, itemprop: 'name', content: venue.title)
        content_tag(:meta, nil, itemprop: 'address', content: venue.address)
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: try calling `raw` on the output of the content_tag

Comment: could you be a little clearer, please?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this code:

```
def opening_times_meta(venue)
  content_tag(:div, nil, class: 'facility-type', itemscope: true, itemtype: 'http://schema.org/Event') do
    [
      content_tag(:meta, nil, content: venue.title, itemprop: 'name' ),
      content_tag(:div, nil, class: 'hidden', itemprop: 'location', itemscope: true, itemtype: 'http://schema.org/Place') do
        [
          content_tag(:meta, nil, itemprop: 'sameAs', content: request.original_url),
          content_tag(:meta, nil, itemprop: 'name', content: venue.title),
          content_tag(:meta, nil, itemprop: 'address', content: venue.address)
        ].join.html_safe
      end
    ].join.html_safe
  end
end
```

but IMO much better is to move that to a view.